# Mysql: Select Count And IN Clause in One Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have query like

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) As Publishid164 FROM  `comments` WHERE  `publishid` =164
```

it will get Count of One publishid=164

But I wanted to pass more plublish id like

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) Publishid FROM  `comments` WHERE  `publishid` IN  (164,165)
```

But I wanted different counts of publish id

How can i do that

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `GROUP BY publishid` try `SELECT COUNT( * ) Publishid FROM  `comments` WHERE  `publishid` IN  (164,165) GROUP BY publishid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need  a count for each publishid you must group by

```
SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM comments 
WHERE publishid IN (164,165) 
GROUP BY publishid
```

of if you need  also publishid column

```
SELECT publishid, COUNT( * )
FROM comments 
WHERE publishid IN (164,165) 
GROUP BY publishid
```